# Does minecraft servers scale well on multi thread CPU?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I'm going to run small, heavily modded server and I can't find this anywhere. How many threads can an MC server use efficiently?

I'm choosing between 5GHz 2/4t and 4Ghz 6/12t.

Edit:

I'm asking about production data of an up to date server and if it can utilize more than 4 heavy threads. The question everybody flaging as duplicate is quite old (10 versions back) and it only tells me: How can I force JVM Garbage Collector to use more threads.

Im concerned about world loading, tick handeling, dimension handeling, entities managment and so on. Not about GC.

Comment: I can't directly answer your question, but for your purposes CPU is mostly irrelevant; memory is vastly more important than clock speed. Also, clock speed is much less descriptive than it used to be, due to more specific pipelines and instructions in silicon. Get mostly whatever CPU, focus your research on your memory.

Answer (score -1):

Minecraft is mostly single-threaded. So unless you are running a hosting company, it is best to have single-thread performance cpus